# Check out this limerick contest we're sponsoring

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I spoke with some of you [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/conversation/recommended-elu-questions) the other day about questions that would be relevant to this [limerick contest](http://stancarey.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/five-line-rhyme-time-a-limerick-contest/) we're sponsoring on Sentence First, and I just wanted to let you know it went up today! The author, Stan, gave us a really nice write up and linked to a bunch of questions! Check it out and feel free to enter.

Comment: I was going to vote to close as "not a real question", but you cleverly inserted a question mark at the end of the title. Foiled again!

Comment: I meant for this to be on meta - to tell everyone about the contest. Did it accidentally go to the actual site?

Comment: No, you're fine. There is a "not a real question" close reason on meta sites but it really shouldn't be there, I think.

Comment: I think you misworded. The questions in the sample chat might be relevant for the nature of ELU, not to the limerick contest.

Comment: it was just a reference so that people who have already discussed the limerick contest would know it's the same one

Comment: I see. [Exclamation points in titles are automatically converted to question marks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102807/please-remove-the-s-title-filter-from-meta).

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

And the winners have been chosen! From [Sentence first](http://stancarey.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/five-line-rhyme-time-a-limerick-contest/):

> **Update 2:** So many good limericks were entered, I wish I had more prizes to give.
>   Ten times more. But I’m happy to announce the following three winners:
>
> Second prize (B) goes to Mike Page:
>
> > If engaged in a contest with Inuit
> >     in snow-naming, please, discontinue it!
> >      We can hardly compete
> >     Using “slush”, “powder”, “sleet”…
> >     You’ve got to be Inuit to win you it!
>
> for imaginative rhyming and inspired silliness. (Alongside his
>   limerick I must recommend [this essay](http://users.utu.fi/freder/Pullum-Eskimo-VocabHoax.pdf) (PDF) on Eskimo words for snow.)
>
> Second prize (A) goes to Lisa Liel:
>
> > Grammarians like to explain
> >     That the verbing of nouns is inane
> >     But friending is fine
> >     It’s no different in kind
> >     Than contacting me to complain
>
> More sense in 25 words than you can shake a derivational suffix at.
>   (Note: after the verb contact (in the sense *get in touch with*) arose
>   in the early 20th century, it was “greeted with open hostility by
>   purists for several decades”, according to Robert Burchfield.)
>
> First prize goes to Paraic O’Donnell:
>
> > There was once a pig’s ear of a language,
> >     Romance scraps in a Jerry-built sandwich.
> >     Mostly used for rude jokes,
> >     It became for some folks
> >     Something nothing was seriouser than which.
>
> for fine philological punning and wonderful syntactical funning that
>   made me laugh much longer than I ought to admit.
>
> Congratulations to Mike, Lisa, and Paraic, thanks to Stack Exchange
>   for their generosity, and thank you all again for taking part!